# MySql Update query works, but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

The below UPDATE Query works just fine when I throw it into Workbench, however when I try to run it through php it does nothing?  Any Ideas?

I have tried structure of table for `TURNOVERSCORE` as varchar(100) and Float, table1.item and t2.item are Primary keys.

Provides Error when using mysql_error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE table1 JOIN (SELECT count(*) as cnt, ITEM FROM table2 WHERE ' at line 2

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pw");
$turnoverquery = "UPDATE table1 
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as cnt, item FROM table2 WHERE table2.TRANS_DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY item) t2 
ON table1.item = t2.item

SET table1.TURNOVERSCORE=CASE
WHEN t2.cnt/12 < 1 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN .05
WHEN t2.cnt/12 >= 1 AND t2.cnt/12 < 4 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN .5
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 4 AND table1.CAT = 'E' THEN 1
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) <= 5 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .05
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 6 AND (t2.cnt/12) < 11 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .25
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 11 AND (t2.cnt/12) < 21 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN .5
WHEN (t2.cnt/12) >= 21 AND table1.CAT != 'E' THEN 1 END";

mysql_query($turnoverquery);
```

Comment: What does `mysql_error` return?

Comment: is your data getting updated in work bench , Can you please clarify this and also can you please put table dumps here so that we can help you out

Comment: You atleast put structure oof tables

Comment: Data is getting updated in Workbench successfully

Comment: ARe you selecting DB can you please put whole code starting from way you are connecting to execution

Comment: I am asking because some times there will be privilage problem

Comment: Ok I believe it has something to do with my `WHERE` clause, hence the `mysql_error`

Comment: Refrain from using `mysql_` functions as they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). Research `mysqli_` or `PDO`. You should add `or die(mysql_error());` to your `mysql_query` and `mysql_connect`.

Comment: @njk How do you think he posted the error message if he didn't use mysql_error()?

Comment: I got it, I had to add the database to the table name `db.table` and `db.table2` thanks you @aravind.udayashankara

Comment: Try using backticks for your table names. Make sure you do not have any hidden characters before UPDATE.. if you copied and pasted the code to the editor.

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara well spotted, all of us missed the simplest thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php query required me to identify the database, (of course).  In Workbench, once your database is selected you do not need to add the `db.tablename` to a query, whereas you must in php if you have not already identified it with your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses don't match. You have `GROUP BY ITEM)` twice in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you for that, I edited post, it is not actually in there twice was an error copying code into question.

Comment: Is that now the EXACT query that appears in your PHP? If there's a syntax error, and you're editing when copying, you might be fixing it while copying it so we can't see it.

Comment: Understood...it is exactly how it appears in my PHP.

Comment: I got it, I had to add the database to the table name `db.table` and `db.table2`

Comment: That shouldn't cause a syntax error, it should complain "Table 'table1' doesn't exist". Unless your table names happen to be SQL keywords. But `table1` and `table2` aren't keywords.

Comment: true that is very strange but I did manage to get it once I added the database name

Comment: What are the actual names of the tables (I'll bet they aren't really table1 and table2 like in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Just converting my comment there to answer .

You need to select DB before execution , Or add database to the table name .